# How to ignore the last two words in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I need a formula that will return the County, separate from the code and date.

```
Kent BEC100 30/09/14
```

Not all counties are one word so I need a formula that ignores the last two words, I have one that will find the last word, second last word, first word, but I need one that will pull everything except the last two words. There are occasions where the county isn't present so I'm thinking I need to add an `ISERROR` in?

```
Bedford BED101 30/09/14 
BLA102 30/09/14
Lancs BOL100 30/09/14
Coventry, West Midla COV100 30/09/14
west Sussex CRA101 30/09/14
```

Comment: Are the words always separated by exactly one space?

Comment: Yes because I've already used TRIM on them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string does not contain a pipe *and is already trimmed*, then use

`=LEFT(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","|",-1+LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))-1)`

Here's how it works:

`LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")` is the number of spaces.

`SUBSTITUTE` inserts a pipe at the penultimate space (with the help of my `-1`)

`FIND` gets the position of that pipe.

`LEFT` extracts the string up to that point.

If your string does contain a pipe, then use a different character. You can enclose the whole thing inside an `IFERROR` (you allude to this in the question) if you need more robustness.

Answer (score 2):

In your examples code and date are always the same length so this formula will work if that always holds

`=TRIM(MID(A1,1,LEN(A1)-15))`

Comment: +1, use this solution if possible. My biggest fault is that I lean too much on rigour at the expense of maintainability.